# Finding the maximum of an xts column in a specified date range

Tags: r, max, xts

I would like to find the maximum of the 'High' column between two date ranges that I can specify. So for example, the maximum between `2017-09-01` and `2017-09-04` is `1.29444`.

Here is my data

```
              Open    High     Low   Close
2017-09-01 1.29360 1.29951 1.29052 1.29495
2017-09-03 1.29600 1.29660 1.29444 1.29535
2017-09-04 1.29536 1.29643 1.29124 1.29300
2017-09-05 1.29306 1.30440 1.29088 1.30331
2017-09-06 1.30331 1.30820 1.30181 1.30471
2017-09-07 1.30472 1.31381 1.30325 1.31319
2017-09-08 1.31319 1.32239 1.31233 1.31945
2017-09-10 1.31816 1.31978 1.31736 1.31769
2017-09-11 1.31769 1.32223 1.31593 1.31764
2017-09-12 1.31766 1.33145 1.31703 1.33097
2017-09-13 1.33096 1.33286 1.31836 1.32040
2017-09-14 1.32039 1.34055 1.31501 1.33955
2017-09-15 1.33955 1.36159 1.33922 1.35871
2017-09-17 1.35579 1.36029 1.35579 1.35921
2017-09-18 1.35921 1.36181 1.34646 1.35176
2017-09-19 1.35176 1.35515 1.34683 1.35178
2017-09-20 1.35178 1.36573 1.34517 1.34914
2017-09-21 1.34914 1.35861 1.34706 1.35761
2017-09-22 1.35760 1.35955 1.34496 1.34935
2017-09-24 1.34872 1.35339 1.34832 1.35261
2017-09-25 1.35262 1.35706 1.34308 1.34816
2017-09-26 1.34816 1.35139 1.34094 1.34385
2017-09-27 1.34386 1.34389 1.33634 1.33753
2017-09-28 1.33754 1.34551 1.33427 1.34159
2017-09-29 1.34160 1.34258 1.33497 1.33963
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subset data easily within xts using a string date in the "YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD" format. So the max of the high column would be something like:

```
max(df.xts$High["2017-09-01/2017-09-04"])
```

If your data is in a dataframe called `df.xts`. You can also add the `na.rm=T` argument to the max function if there are NA values in your dataset, which will exclude those in computing the maximum rather than returning NA.

Comment: My dates are coded so can't just add in a date, `DateSelect<-c("2017-09-17")` and `S<-as.character(index(MinDate))`

Comment: @User314159 Your dates in the rownames of an xts-object are necessarily character values. The `[.xts` function will parse a character value passed as the first object.

Comment: @42-: xts objects do not have rownames. The first element of the `dimnames` list is always `NULL`. xts objects a matrix with an 'index' attribute (which is printed where rownames are usually printed). The 'index' attribute must be an ordered vector (like zoo), but also time-based. The index is implemented internally as the number of seconds from the UNIX epoch.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I may be wrong about zoo objects as well. I’ll go check.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Date column stored as row numbers? 
Maybe want to load the data in a way that we have a Date column. Then this will work.

```
#Ensure Date Column is in Date format: 
library(lubridate) 
df$Date <- ymd(df$date) 

# Subset by date
new.df <- subset(df, Date >= as.POSIXct("2017-09-01") & Date <= as.POSIXct("2017-09-04")) 

# Find max
max(new.df$High)
```

Comment: My data is in xts so not sure if date column is stored as row numbers. Tried to install package lubridate, and it fails to download.

Comment: Only reason for lubridate is to convert a date to Date format, so that we can subset between dates. If you are not using xts but normal data frame or so then this will work above. otherwise the other solutions will work for xts?